# How to create 'dynamic' parameters from an excel table to apply to a oracle query through Power Query

Tags: excel, oracle, dynamic, parameters, powerquery

I am trying to add data to a report (an excel table) from an oracle table.

Easy enough to get data and merge - but my problem is I only want the oracle query to pull from the ID's listed in the report (excel table).

Any thoughts on setting up these parameters?

Thank you!

Comment: Any examples? Example of oracle query you are using now that you are trying to convert to PowerQuery. Example of powerquery code you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and include what you have already tried and what you're getting instead of your expected results.